# Tube Physics Body acting like SCNCylinder, but how to make it act like SCNTube?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to make a tube and its physics body like so in SceneKit.

```
let BoxGeometry = SCNTube(innerRadius: 5, outerRadius: 12.5, height: 4)
Box = SCNNode(geometry: BoxGeometry)
Box.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(Float(M_PI_2/8), 0, 1, 0)
Box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
Box.physicsBody?.mass = 5
Box.categoryBitMask = colorCategory
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(Box)
```

However, when another object falls onto this object it does not pass through the center. Instead it sits appearing to be levitating in air. It is acting like the physics body is a complete cylinder, not like the tube with the hole in the middle. How can I fix this so that objects can pass through the center? The tubes appearance looks as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Style point: Swift prefers, but doesn't enforce, that InitialCapCamelCase names be used for types (classes, structs, enums, protocols). For better interoperability with various tools and better readability for sharing your code with others, use lowerCamelCase for variable/constant names: `let boxGeometry`, `box = SCNNode`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dynamic bodies in SceneKit must be convex. (If you look into the general theory behind collision detection in games, i.e. not just SceneKit, you'll find that there are massive differences in speed and efficiency between collision detection on convex versus concave shapes.) A tube is a concave shape — it has a hole in it.

Luckily, your tube is being used as a static body. For static bodies only, there's an option to make the physics shape (an approximation of) a concave geometry:

```
let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: tube, 
    options: [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey: SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron])
box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: shape)
```

There is a performance cost to this. If you find your framerate limited by CPU usage after this change, or if you want to have a dynamic body be (effectively) concave, you might get better performance by making a physics shape that's a compound of several other shapes — e.g. build a dummy node hierarchy (not one that's actually in your scene) containing a bunch of cylinders or boxes arranged into a ring, then make a physics shape from them with `SCNPhycsicsShape(node:options:)`.

Comment: My apologies the body was just static for testing purposes, the goal is to have it dynamic

Comment: Then you'll need to use a compound of convex shapes to approximate your concave shape, as summarized at the end of my answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that the options only worked for static?

Comment: `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron` works only for static. For dynamic, you can construct a compound shape from several nodes/shapes with `SCNPhycsicsShape(node:options:)` — those shapes have to be convex (and preferably basic geometries like sphere, box, etc), but together they can form a concave arrangement of shapes.

Comment: Could you please help me how to detect collision if ball pass through the object. here is question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135793/arkit-ball-pass-through-torus-hole-collision-detection

Answer (score 0):

Change the shape of your physicsBody to match the geometry of your tube.