# SceneKit – Concave collision box

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Im importing an object in DAE format and I'm wanting to use it as a collision object however it is concave, but I'm having trouble implementing this in code:

```
func addCollisionBox() {

    let collisionBoxNode = SCNNode()
    let collisionBox = importedCollisionBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pCube2", recursively: false)
    collisionBoxNode.addChildNode(collisionBox!)
    collisionBoxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    collisionBoxNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(30, 20, 50)
    //collisionBoxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody()
    collisionBoxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.bodyWithType(SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron, shape: collisionBox)  // This line errors
    collisionBoxNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
    collisionBoxNode.name = "collisionBox"

    theScene.rootNode.addChildNode(collisionBoxNode)   
}
```

Cant get the line of code to work which has this in it `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron` as commented in the code.

Comment: Code please? As stated, your question is quite vague and it's hard to see what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I havent written any code yet but will try some out tonight. Think of a cereal box with the lid open. I want dynamic objects to collide internally with this box. If I create a box using SCNBox, my dynamic objects that are initalised inside this box, immediately pop to the outside during simulation. I know how collision work based on the objects normals but Im not that familiar with SceneKit.

Comment: Ive just updated my original post, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SceneKit Tube Physics Body acting like cylinder, how to make it act like tube?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391763/scenekit-tube-physics-body-acting-like-cylinder-how-to-make-it-act-like-tube)

Comment: I suggest you leave it open, write an answer, and accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "concave" physics body, per `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron`, must still be "solid" in some sense, and the implied behavior for that collision type is to keep other bodies outside the "solid" form of the body. As such, your cube still has a "solid" interior even if you set its shape type to concave.

(What the concave shape type *does* do for you is let you make a solid shape that is non-convex — for example, a cube where one of the faces bows inward to produce a bowl shape.)

If you want to confine other bodies to a box-shaped volume, you'll need to create walls: that is, put *a few* physics bodies *around* the volume you want to enclose. Here's a quick utility function for something like that:

```
func wallsForBox(box: SCNBox, thickness: CGFloat) -> SCNNode {

    func physicsWall(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, length: CGFloat) -> SCNNode {
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: width, height: height, length: length, chamferRadius: 0))
        node.physicsBody = .staticBody()
        return node
    }

    let parent = SCNNode()

    let leftWall = physicsWall(thickness, height: box.height, length: box.length)
    leftWall.position.x = -box.width / 2
    parent.addChildNode(leftWall)

    let rightWall = physicsWall(thickness, height: box.height, length: box.length)
    rightWall.position.x = box.width / 2
    parent.addChildNode(rightWall)

    let frontWall = physicsWall(box.width, height: box.height, length: thickness)
    frontWall.position.z = box.length / 2
    parent.addChildNode(frontWall)

    let backWall = physicsWall(box.width, height: box.height, length: thickness)
    backWall.position.z = -box.length / 2
    parent.addChildNode(backWall)

    let topWall = physicsWall(box.width, height: thickness, length: box.length)
    topWall.position.y = box.height / 2
    parent.addChildNode(topWall)

    let bottomWall = physicsWall(box.width, height: thickness, length: box.length)
    bottomWall.position.y = -box.height / 2
    parent.addChildNode(bottomWall)

    return parent
}
```

This creates a node hierarchy containing visible walls as separate nodes, but you could easily modify it to create invisible walls and/or a single node with a compound physics body. (See [`SCNPhysicsShape`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsShape_Class/index.html).)

Comment: I did something very similar to this originally but not as elegant as your code. Also I foresee this method may be easier to control the width and height of each plane with the current view dimensions.